# appcelerator android development tools

Tags: appcelerator

When i go to window > show view > terminal

and type in

appc ti setup

and then select option "2"

i can see it says, amidst a bunch of stuff

```
Android Environment
  √  sdk                installed (C:\android-sdk-win)
  !  tools              untested version 24.4.1; may or may not work
  √  platform tools     installed (v23.1.0)
```

I'm only using the appcelerator studio to setup everything - why did it go and download a version that it says "may or may not work" and how do i tell it to go and get a version that it is confident will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do i tell it to go and get a version that it is confident will work

In the tools folder of the android sdk (you will need to find this) there is an android binary (windows its android.exe).

*EDIT - in mine it is android.bat*

Run that and it should start the Android SDK Manager for you. You can then pick and choose additional tool versions and APIs to download.

Comment: thanks for this - do you know what "tools" the cli is referring to? Nothing that shows up in my android.bat is version 24.4.1, so i don't really know what i'm changing...

Answer (score 1):

You need to update Android SDK and tools from time to time, go to `C:\android-sdk-win\tools\` (common folder for Android SDK) and run `android.bat`.

This is what I see currently

```
Android Environment
V  sdk                installed (C:\android-sdk-win)
V  tools              installed (v25.2.5)
V  platform tools     installed (v25.0.5)
V  build tools        installed (v23.0.3)
```